# How to get Review for products collection magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, phtml, ratings, product-review

> Actually i want to get Review Rating and summary count.Please check below code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); 

$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product); 
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeManager  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code given below.

Please change the $sku for the product for which you want to get the review and reting summery.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; 
$params = $_SERVER; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); 
$sku = '24-MB04';
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku); //you can also use load($id) if you know product id
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product); 
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeManager  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
echo "<br />Rating Summary=". $ratingSummary;
echo "<br />Review Count=".$reviewCount;

?>
```